# Firestore get only updated documents, and sync deleted ones with cache

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have read about ways to only fetch updated documents from firestore database using lastModified property with timestamp and only fetch documents after latest timestamp from cache.

However I was reading Version 10.12.0 release notes of Firebase iOS SDK firestore feature and it says the following:
https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios#10.15.0

`To save on network bandwidth, the server only replies with the documents that have changed since the timestamp encoded in the resume token.`

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/pull/11457

Does that mean I need not implement lastModified property in my documents?

However when I do a fresh fetch, I get back all the documents in a collection regardless if they changed or not. I use .count to figure out the number of documents. Could it be possible that the server is only replying with the changed documents only and then it gets merged with the cache which explains why document count stays the same?

From the same document:

`To avoid this expensive re-running of the query from scratch the server has been modified to also reply with the names of the documents that had not changed since the timestamp encoded in the resume token. With this additional information, the client can determine which documents in its local cache were deleted or removed, and directly put them into "limbo" without having to re-run the entire query from scratch.`

I tried running a get() query using .whereField("lastModified", isGreaterThan: lastModified),
then after, running a cache query to get all the synced data, the deleted documents are not removed from the cache, they are only removed if I run the full query without .whereField. But then if I do run without .whereField, I get back all the documents which is pointless because most of them are not changed.

I use Firebase iOS SDK version 10.15.0, and Xcode version 14.3.1

```
private func getThreads() async
    {
        let query = db.db.collection("Boards").document(board.id).collection("Threads")

        if let lastMod = Query.lastMod(from: threads)
        {
            let queryServer = query.whereField("lastMod", isGreaterThan: lastMod)
            await db.get0(dataType: ModelThread.self, query: queryServer, from: .server)
        }
        else
        {
            await db.get0(dataType: ModelThread.self, query: query, from: .server)
        }
        
        let returned = await db.get0(dataType: ModelThread.self, query: query, from: .cache)
        sort(threads: returned)
    }
```

The `if let lastMod = Query.lastMod(from: threads)` just gets the latest Date from the lastMod property in the array of documents, if empty (does not exist) just do a fresh fetch.